# Returning results not displayed with typeahead and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I was spending all my time to resolve this problem.

I tried to make functionaly an ajax call with bootstrap+typeahead.

If someone can help me, it will be great

This my **HTML** part :

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Parent</label>
   <div class="controls">
     <input type="text" value="" name="parent" id="parent" autocomplete="off"  data-provide="typeahead" />
   </div>
```

This is my **JS** part :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#parent').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
        return $.ajax({
            minLength: 1,
            url: "/ajax/places/",
            type: 'POST',
            data : 'query='+query,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                return typeof data == 'undefined' ? false : process(data);
        }
    }); 
        }
    });
});
```

I can see Ajax fired, and the **Json**, here it is an extract :

```
[
         "name": "Aix"
    ,      "name": "Aix"
    ,      "name": "Aix en Diois"
    ,      "name": "Aix en Ergny"
    ,      "name": "Aix en Issart"
    ,      "name": "Aix en Othe"
    ,      "name": "Aix en Provence"
    ,      "name": "Aix la Fayette"
    ,      "name": "Aix les Bains"
    ,      "name": "Aix Noulette"
    ,      "name": "Aixe sur Vienne"
    ,      "name": "Artaix"
    ,      "name": "Baix"
    ,      "name": "Baixas"
    ,      "name": "Benaix"
    ,      "name": "Caix"
    ,      "name": "Caixas"
    ,      "name": "Caixon"
    ,      "name": "Carhaix Plouguer"
    ,      "name": "Chaix"
]
```

If I "console.log(data)", everything seems to be ok.

Thanks you for your help !!

---

It works if I remove the "name" property, like that :

```
[
         "Aix"
    ,      "Aix"
    ,      "Aix en Diois"
    ,      "Aix en Ergny"
    ,      "Aix en Issart"
    ,      "Aix en Othe"
    ,      "Aix en Provence"
    ,      "Aix la Fayette"
    ,      "Aix les Bains"
    ,      "Aix Noulette"
    ,      "Aixe sur Vienne"
    ,      "Artaix"
    ,      "Baix"
    ,      "Baixas"
    ,      "Benaix"
    ,      "Caix"
    ,      "Caixas"
    ,      "Caixon"
    ,      "Carhaix Plouguer"
    ,      "Chaix"
]
```

But now How can I use Id and name ?

EDIT : I used this [Bootstrap typeahead ajax result format - Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901535/bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-result-format-example) and found solution

I'll show you what I did with other process.

Comment: That can't be your JSON, that's not a valid JSON object, nor it is a valid JavaScript object, or even array literal. Are you sure this is the JSON you're getting?

Comment: Maybe he typed square brackets instead of curly brackets. It could happen.

Comment: But that doesn't explain the multiple "name" properties. (Which is probably invalid JSON)

Comment: What exactly is the problem. If your `source` function returns an array as you show in your "answer", then should work.

Answer (score 0):

The "stuff" returned is not valid JSON, and that's probably why the client-side Javascript is unable to deal with it.

If it is suppose to be a JSON Object, it should look like this:

```
   { "name1": "Aix"
      , "name2": "Aix"
      , "name3": "Aix en Diois"
```

etcetera. (Note that the attribute names need to be unique.  It is legal in theory to have multiple attributes with identical names.  However this won't work.  All JSON parsers I've ever encountered will discard all but one of the corresponding values.)

If it is suppose to be a JSON array it should look like this:

```
   { "Aix"
      , "Aix"
      , "Aix en Diois"
```

etcetera.  Or maybe:

```
   [ {"name": "Aix"}
      , {"name": "Aix"}
      , {"name": "Aix en Diois"}
```

etcetera, which is a JSON array of objects.

Reference:

- [The syntax of JSON](http://www.json.org).

Answer (score 0):

This is my complete solution :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Parent</label>
    <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" value="" class="typeahead" autocomplete="off"  data-provide="typeahead" />
       <input type="hidden" value="" id="parent" name="parent" />
   </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {

            category = $("#category").val();
            list = [];

            return $.ajax({
                minLength: 3,
                url: "/ajax/places/",
                type: 'POST',
                data : { query: query, categorySon: category },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {

                    var resultList = result.aaData.map(function (item) {

                        list[item.name + ' - ' + item.code + ' (' + item.category + ')'] = item.id;
                        return item.name + ' - ' + item.code + ' (' + item.category + ')';

                    });

                    return process(resultList);

                }

            }); 
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            $("#parent").val(list[item]);
            return item;
        }
    });
});
```