# Twitter bootstrap typeahead return multiple values and fillup the editbox

Tags: php, mysql, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm new in bootstrap and i need some help please, i want to create a typeahead drop-down that return 3 values from my mysql database when the user search for a contact name in **"ContactName" TEXTBOX** and fill up 3 edit box with the information of 
-contact name
-Telephone Number
-email address
thanks a lot on advance for all your effort

this is the code that i try it to return one value i need to modified to return all those tree value
Now when i try to search the contact name it will return with correctly with no question to ask but i don't know how to modify the code to bring 3 value like i mention above

```
enter code here

**php page: Customer.php**
-------------------------------------------
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "db34218";

$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass) or die("connection in not ready <br>");
$result=mysql_select_db($database) or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {

$query = $_REQUEST['query'];

$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT ContactName, Telephone, Email FROM customer WHERE   ContactName LIKE '%{$query}%'");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row['ContactName'];
}

echo json_encode ($array); //Return the JSON Array
}
?>




**html and java page and some php: Customersearch.php**
------------------------------------------------
<body>
.
.
.
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4">
            <label>ContactName&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" name="ContactName" value="<?php echo     $row_Recordset_QuoteCustomer['ContactName']?>" data-provide="typeahead" class="typeahead input-xlarge" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="span2">
            <label>Telephone&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="<?php echo     htmlentities($row_Recordset_QuoteCustomer['Telephone'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" class="span12">
          </div>
          <div class="span2">
            <label>Email &nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email " value="<?php echo     htmlentities(row_Recordset_QuoteCustomer['Email '], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" class="span12">
          </div>
.........
.
.
.
.
.
.

<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="../js/SpecWorkPages/getItemsList.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'Customer.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                process(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($RecordsetQuote);
mysql_free_result($Recordset_QuoteStatus);
mysql_free_result($Recordset_QuoteCustomer);
?>
```

Comment: Without any code it's going to be hard for anyone to help. If you don't have any yet, I would suggest taking a look here https://gist.github.com/Yavari/1891669 for a good start. You can also check out other SO posts on the subject with a quick search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap+typeahead

Comment: ok i add my code can any one help me to modifier my code thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are getting results back but unable to populate the input fields. Although I don't use Twitter Bootstrap typeahead I do something very similar with jQuery's autocomplete feature. The code below is untested and of course you'll need to modify it for yourself but hopefully will be of some help.

See this working jsFiddle [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G3BPv/) for something similar.

**PHP**

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    array_push($array,array('ContactName'=>$row['ContactName'],'Telephone'=>$row['Telephone'],'Email'=>$row['Email']));
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

You can check what gets returned by manually entering the URL (ex: yoursite/Customer.php?query=SomeContactName). You should see something similar to this:

```
[{"ContactName":"Some Contact","Telephone":"5555555555","Email":"email@whatever.com"},
 {"ContactName":"Some Other Contact","Telephone":"5555555555","Email":"anotheremail@whatever.com"}]
```

**HTML/Javascript**

```
<script>
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Customer.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                // data: 'query=' + query,
                data: 'query=' + $('#contactName').val(),
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var results = data.map(function(item) {
                        var someItem = { contactname: item.ContactName, telephone: item.Telephone, email: item.Email };
                        return JSON.stringify(someItem.contactname);
                    });
                    return process(results);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        updater: function(item) {
            // This may need some tweaks as it has not been tested
            var obj = JSON.parse(item);
            return item;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here are a couple other posts that you might want to take a look at [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/738262) and [Bootstrap typeahead ajax result format - Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959406/738262)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I really appreciate i'm going to try to modifier my pages thanks a lot

Comment: sorry to bug you again Brain with my code i tried to add your code to my page so it didn't work event the edit box for contactname when i enter the name it stop searching it i'm not sure what to do i need your help again, the contactname box it should be like the autocomplet in jquery when i start to type the contact name it will return all name found in my mysql table my code above work perfect for that scenario but i need to get the phone and email to to fillup the other 2 editbox please help.

Comment: See my update. I set the minLength to 1 so it starts searching as soon as you start typing and as you are typing it passes the value of contactName to your PHP page. I'm assuming that you are trying to populate the phone and email fields when a contact name is selected (as you can see this is what I'm doing in the jsFiddle I provided).

Comment: oh finally a got something thanks a lot honestly thanks alot you are amazing. i still have one question the drop down menu for the contact name when i do the research for the contact name it display in that format [{"ContactName":"Some Contact","Telephone":"55555","Email":"email@whatever.com"}, {"ContactName":"Some OtherContact","Telephone":"555555","Email":"anotheremail@whatever.com"}] is there a way to display only the list of Contact name without the telephone number and the email.since the telephone number and the email going to be display in the telephone number and the email edit box

Comment: Updated answer which only displays Contact Name. The change is where you return JSON.stringify. I can't write the entire code for you, you won't learn anything that way. Not trying to be rude, but you're going to have to play around with it and figure some of it out by yourself.

Comment: i know but i'm trying to understand the code and modified but it's not working so i find different way so try it, it work but i'm not able to pull the data from my mysql database i try to modified but no result any help