# Passing value of selected product in live search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image: image of searchbox]

I'm using a jQuery live search script but it only passes on the `product_name`, how do i get it to pass on the product_id and alert that id in jQuery?

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    }); 

    $('.typeahead').on('change', function () {
        alert($(this).val());// outputs only the text i have typed
    });//how do i get the product_id from php request?

});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","products");
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from products where product_name LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $array[] = $row['product_name'];
        //$array[] = $row['product_id'];//How do i pass this value with the product name and alert it in JS?
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bs-example">
<input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
</div>
```

The output from the auto-populated search dropdown(see image):

```
<p>First Product</p>
```

This has an id of "1" but I need to pass it from PHP and retrieve it with jQuery.

Comment: [Twitter bootstrap typeahead return multiple values and fillup the editbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498384/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-return-multiple-values-and-fillup-the-editbox)

Comment: With that code anyone can wipe your database just by entering an URL. Lookup "SQL injection" and fix that first, before anything else.